# NgbModal is displaying on top in IE chrome its in center

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, ng-bootstrap

I am using @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap for modal window, in chrome its working fine but in internet explorer modal popups on the top in the browser.

I am setting following ModalOptions which works for chrome but not for IE

```
  const statusOptions: NgbModalOptions = {
      backdrop: 'static',
      keyboard: false,
      size: 'sm',
      centered: true
    };
```

I am using angular 6 and TypeScript.

Comment: what is your ie version ?

Comment: Internet explorer 11